# How to get values of variables from one Postman environment into another

Tags: postman, newman

I have a scenario where I have two APIs (V1 and V2). I also have a Postman collection with requests like this already setup

```
{{base}}/myApi/{{Version}}/myResource
```

What I would like to do is have a separate environment for each version (e.g. Dev_V1 and Dev_V2) so it’s easy for users/testers to know exactly what version they are using. Most variables will be common between both environment. Is there a way to pull some of the values from one environment into the other without duplicating the value (copy past)? In other words; how do I go about getting the value of a variable from Dev_V1 into Dev_V2 without copying and pasting it into Dev_V2?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4968

The feature is not supported yet but a feature request is already opened